# Python http.client giving empty string when I use response.read().decode()

Tags: python, api, http.client

I am using http.client to hit a POST api and get the json response. My code is working correctly when I print response.read(). However, for some reason, this response is limited to only 20 results and the total count of results is over 20,000. I want to get the complete response in a variable using response.read().decode(), I am hoping that the variable will contain the complete json string. The issue is that I am getting an empty string when I used decode(). How do I get this done? How do I get the complete results?

```
import http.client

host = 'jooble.org'
key = 'API_KEY'

connection = http.client.HTTPConnection(host)
#request headers
headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/json"}
#json query
body = '{ "keywords": "sales", "location": "MA"}'
connection.request('POST','/api/' + key, body, headers)
response = connection.getresponse()
print(response.status, response.reason)
print(response.read())
print(response.read().decode())
```

Comment: Why don't you use the higher-level `requests` module?

Comment: The API code is provided by the website itself. Not sure how to convert this code into a version using requests module. Will look into it but it would be preferred if I can solve it using http.client

Comment: You're calling `response.read()` twice. The first call reads the entire response, there's nothing left for the second call to read, so there's nothing to decode.

Comment: That did work. Unfortunately, still got 20 results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `response.read()` twice. `response` is a stream, so each call to `read()` continues from where the previous one ended. Since the first call is reading the entire response, the second one doesn't read anything.

If you want to print the encoded and decoded response, assign `response.read()` to a variable, then decode that.

```
data = response.read()
print(data)
print(data.decode())
```

But this can be done more simply using the `requests` module.

```
import requests

host = 'jooble.org'
key = 'API_KEY'

body = { "keywords": "sales", "location": "MA"}

response = requests.post(f'https://{host}/api/{key}', json=body)

print(response.content)
```

Note that in this version `body` is a dictionary, not a string. The `json` parameter automatically converts it to JSON.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I am still getting 20 results. Maybe I can write the results to a file and that will do the job? Will explore this.

Comment: Many APIs limit the the number of results you can get in each call. Check the documentation to see if you can specify the number to return, and how to get the next batch. You'll need to call it in a loop.

Comment: Thanks. 1 thing I have also noticed is that the results page has 20 results initially, when I scroll down more, the other (probably 20 more) results load and get displayed. Could this be a reason for this? If yes, can this be solved via some sort of timeout? Not sure..

Comment: Do you have a link to the API documentation? It should mention pagination.

Comment: Unfortunately, documentation for this API is not available publicly

Comment: Then you're on your own. Search it for parameters used for pagination.